# Accordion effect and tables

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion

I have a page that has tabs in it. Each tab houses different information. One tab is a list of various resellers each with a singular location. I now need to add an accordion effect to one of the resellers so that it shows all of it's 28 locations. This is one of few times that using tables is still functional because it is a grid format.

My question is since this reseller data is housed in a table which resides in a tab, is it going to be possible to

1. Expand the length of the page
2. Expand the length of content area in this tab.
3. Expand the cell area in a table to show these other locations.
4. Then when clicked on again everything is able to collapse and go back to a singular listing.

Authorized Reseller tab http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/show-projectors/resource.solutions.bbsccms-assets-show-projectors-laserprojectorslandingpage.shtml

Comment: I think if you share a doodle of your structure, that'd help everybody

Comment: URL has been provided

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new TR bellow your reseller, with a single td inside which has `colspan` of 5, then put whatever element inside which you think would imply that the list of location belongs to the reseller mentioned above.

```
    <tr>
        <td width="195" style="padding:5px;"><button onclick='showLocatoins(this, reselleridhere)'>Audio Visual Innovations (DBA: AVI/SPL)</button></td>
        <td width="165" style="padding:5px;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.avispl.com">www.avispl.com</a></td>
        <td width="185" style="padding:5px;">6301 Benjamin Rd., Suite 101</td>
        <td width="140" style="padding:5px;">Tampa, FL 33634</td>
        <td width="75" style="padding:5px;">800-262-6733</td>
    </tr>


function showLocatoins(button, id) {
    loadMoreLocations(function (locations) {//assuming you have an async function for this already
         var td = $("<td colspan='5' class='extra locations'>");
         td.append("<span>more locations:</span>");
         _.each(function(location) {
             td.append("<div class='location'>".text(location));
         });

         td.append($("<button>").text("close").click(function () {td.parent().remove();}));
         //in case you want to give the user a way to close...             

         $(button.parentNode).after($("<tr>").append(td));
    })
}
```

Comment: And this will expand the table area, the div area that the tab is and the length of the page?

Comment: I just saw you are giving the tab div a fixed height. You will need to update that, by measuring your table's height again (or calculating for that matter).